# Variables assigned to document.getElementById accessable outside of closure?

Tags: javascript

Lets say I have a few variables in a closure like so:

```
(function () {  
    var foo = document.getElementById('foo'),  
        bar = 'baz';  
 }());
```

Also assume I have an html element with an id of foo :

```
<h1 id = 'foo'>foo</h1>
```

I then try to access each of the variables in the closure from outside the closure.
First bar :

```
console.log(bar); //logs a reference error 'bar is not defined'
```

Then foo :

```
console.log(foo.innerHTML) // logs 'foo' instead of throwing reference error. Why?
```

Why is it that foo is still accessible outside of the closure?

hear is a jsFiddle if that helps : http://jsfiddle.net/YmDmL/

Comment: If you call the `foo` variable *anything* else, this will show the problem isn't the variables 'leaking', but a holdover from (early/very-old IE), in which elements with an `id` were immediately accessible in the global scope by the name of their `id`; here's [a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/YmDmL/1/), note that I've deleted/removed the `display` assignment.

Comment: Because browsers add elements with an id as variables to the global object.

Comment: @DavidThomas : That seems to be the ticket. I wasn't aware of this behavior. Im assuming that's another reason to avoid extraneous id attributes in HTML markup. If you can post your comment in an answer I would be glad to accept it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'problem' isn't that the `foo` variable defined inside the closure is available outside the closure (as you yourself prove when you get a reference error for `bar`); it's that browsers automagically create variables, in the global scope, for all elements that have an `id` property using that `id` as the variable-name.

In this case:

```
<div id="foo">text in foo</div>
<span id="aSpan">other text, in aSpan</span>
```

Would create two variables, `div` and `aSpan`: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/gj3yf/).

As I suggested, in the comments to your question, if you change your JavaScript to call `foo` *anything* else, you'll see that it becomes apparent that there's no leakage of local-variables:

```
(function () {  
    var whatever = document.getElementById('foo'),  
        bar = 'baz';  
 }());

console.log(foo); // outputs: <div id="foo">text in foo</div>
console.log(whatever); // outputs: Uncaught ReferenceError: whatever is not defined
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/gj3yf/1/).

Answer (score 0):

You can add name space as the following :

```
(function () {  
var foo = document.getElementById('foo'),  
    bar = 'baz';  
}(myNameSpace));
```

and then from outside the closure use:

```
console.log(myNameSpace.bar);
```

Comment: Good to know, but not exactly what I was asking for.